# Distinguishing between blank lines and end of file in Python

Tags: python, file, while-loop, eof, blank-line

A situation that I continually run into is the following:

```
readFile = open("myFile.txt", "r")
while True:
    readLine = readFile.readline()
    if readLine == "":
        #Assume end of file
        break
    #Otherwise, do something with the line
    #...
```

The problem is that the file I am reading contains blank lines. According to the documentation I have read, `file.readline()` will return `"\n"` for a blank line found in a file, but that does not happen for me. If I don't put that blank line condition in the while loop, it continues infinitely, because a `readline()` executed at or beyond the end of the file returns a blank string.

Can somebody help me create a condition that allows the program to read blank lines, but to stop when it reaches the end of the file?

Answer (score 3):

Just use a for loop:

```
for readLine in open("myFile.txt"):
    print(readLine); # Displayes your line contents - should also display "\n"
    # Do something more
```

Stops automatically at end of file.

If you sometimes need an extra line, something like this might work:

```
with open("myFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if needs_extra_line(line):  # Implement this yourself :-)
            line += next(f)  # Add next line to this one
        print(line)
```

Or a generator that yields the chunks you want to use:

```
def chunks(file_object):
    for line in file_object:
        if needs_extra_line(line):
            line += next(file_object)
        yield line
```

Then the function that processes the lines can run a for loop over that generator.

Comment: The only problem I have with that is that for some parts of the file, I have to read two lines in order to gather all of the data I need. In other words, I would execute a second readline() within the same loop. I'm not sure if I can do that using the for loop you describe.

Comment: You can do that if you assign the open file to a variable, and then call `next()` to get the next value out of the iterator. I'll edit.

Comment: @jdrobers Then call `next()` on the file object during the loop, if a `StopIteration` error is raised the file has reached its end.

Comment: Well, I tried converting to a "for" loop and I get the same issue. Blank lines terminate the loop (I have removed the condition to break if readLine == "", btw.) If it means anything, I'm using Python 2.7.5. Are there any other workarounds?

Comment: No, I'm quite sure that if you get a blank line, you have in fact reached the end of the file. Otherwise that's not a line, and it would have continued. Maybe a problem with your file?